# Code runs partially correct for given the input by user (CS50 Introduction to Python pset1)

Tags: python, cs50

I have this task where I implement a program that prompts the user for the answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe and Everything, outputting Yes if the user inputs 42 or (case-insensitively) forty-two or forty two. Otherwise output No.

The below code was the one I tried:

```
def main():
    answer = input("What is the Answer to the Great Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything? ")
    if reply(answer):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
def reply(n):
    y = n.replace("-"," ")
    z = y.lower().strip()

    return (z == "forty two", z == "42")

main()
```

I expected,

```
 input of 50 yields output of No
    expected "No", not "Yes\n"
 input of fifty yields output of No
    expected "No", not "Yes\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is a tuple and as such is always Truthy. Perhaps you meant the boolean `or` instead of comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the condition of the 'answer' variable within the main(), while in the reply() you need to check whether the input is string or number and return it. The way you have it the reply will always be yes.